# Likelihood function for linear regression

Tags: regression, maximum-likelihood, likelihood

For linear regression, the likelihood function can be found with:

[image]

However if your data points are multi-dimensional such that `x`,`y` and  your standard deviation `s`, can be represented as vectors of length 10. How do you adjust the likelihood function?

Would the total log-likelihood be the sum of all the log-likelihoods for each dimension?

Comment: Are you assuming all the correlations are zero?

Comment: Yes I am for my case. But now that you've asked I'm curious about the case when they are correlated if there is a straightforward answer. In that case the standard deviations vectors will be a covariance matrix of 10 by 10. But if you know the answer for uncorrelated case I'd be super happy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the variables are uncorrelated then yes it would just be the sum. Otherwise you must use a multivariate distribution to compute the likelihood.

Comment: Silent downvote to a new member? There's a welcome for ya.

Comment: I wasn't the one who voted your answer down. I have just gave it +1 now to bring it to a zero

Comment: I apologize on behalf of the community for the downvote.  We encourage people to explain their downvotes, *especially* when they are applied to new contributors.